# Target.count causing an Overflow error

Tags: vba, excel, overflow

I have `Worksheet_SelectionChange` function. In the first line I wanted to condition that if more than 1 cell is selected then exit. 
I wrote:

```
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
```

However, when I select the whole worksheet, I get an error message:
"Run time error 6 - Overflow"

It seems like `Target.Count` can't handle such large numbers ?

What can I do to get around this?

Comment: `CountLarge` is what you need.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196838(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Replace `Count` with `CountLarge`.

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196838(v=office.15).aspx

> The `CountLarge` property is functionally the same as the `Count` property, except that the `Count` property will generate an overflow error if the specified range has more than 2,147,483,647 cells (one less than 2048 columns). The `CountLarge` property, however, can handle ranges up to the maximum size for a worksheet, which is 17,179,869,184 cells.

Answer (score 0):

Break the check into rows and columns. This way, the count encounters a maximum of "only" 1,048,576 (rows) as opposed to  17,142,120,448 cells.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    ' do stuff
End Sub
```

Comment: Good idea — but fails if multiple cells are selected using e.g. Ctrl-click.