# How to toggle cell color on selection change

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell reference ranging (`D6:D33`). In this cell range, if I select `D10`,  its background colour should change to red. If the same cell `D10` is selected once again, then its background colour should change to its previous colour.
Likewise it should work for any cell selected within the range `D6:D33`. How to do I modify my incomplete code below to do this?

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D6:D33")) Is Nothing Then
           Range("D10").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 55, 55)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Will the "previous color" vary, or is it constant (e.g. no color or one specific color besides red)?

Answer (score 1):

## True Colors

### Shining Through Version (ADV)

When opening the workbook, all the colors are written into an array. When changing selection if the selection is a cell in the range, the color will change to red, while the previous color will be written to the array. When the color is red, then the former color, which is in the array, will be applied and the red color will be written to the array etc.

Fixed overflow error for version 2007 and later (CountLarge). Fixed 'No Color White Color Error'.

Credits to [BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben) for pointing out various errors.

**Module1**:

```
Option Explicit

Public vnt1 As Variant
Public Const cRng As String = "D6:D33"
Public Const cColor As Long = 255
```

**ThisWorkbook**:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

  Dim i As Long

  With Range(cRng)
    ReDim vnt1(1 To .Rows.Count, 1 To 1) As Long
    For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
      With .Cells(i, 1).Interior
        If .ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
          vnt1(i, 1) = .Color
         Else
          vnt1(i, 1) = -1
        End If
      End With
    Next
  End With

  ' For i = 1 To UBound(vnt1)
  '   Debug.Print i & "  " & vnt1(i, 1)
  ' Next

End Sub
```

**Sheet1**:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim lngDiff As Long
  Dim lngTemp As Long

  If Val(Application.Version) >= 12 Then
    If Selection.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
   Else
    If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  End If

  lngDiff = Range(cRng).Row - 1

  If Not Intersect(Target, Range(cRng)) Is Nothing Then
    With Target.Interior
      If .Color <> cColor Then
        If .ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
          lngTemp = .Color
         Else
          lngTemp = -1
        End If
        vnt1(.Parent.Row - lngDiff, 1) = lngTemp
        .Color = cColor
       Else
        If vnt1(.Parent.Row - lngDiff, 1) <> -1 Then
          .Color = vnt1(.Parent.Row - lngDiff, 1)
         Else
          .ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
        vnt1(.Parent.Row - lngDiff, 1) = cColor
      End If
    End With
  End If

End Sub
```

### Red and White Version (INT)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Val(Application.Version) >= 12 Then
    If Selection.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
   Else
    If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  End If

  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D6:D33")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
      Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
     Else
      Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that OP is using `RGB(255, 55, 55)` so `cColor` should be `3618815`, not `255`. Also `Selection.Cells.Count` will overflow if all cells are selected, you can get around this with `CountLarge` instead of `Count`.

Comment: Sorry for all the commentary, lol, I thought of the same approach. Another note, reading in the `Interior.Color` when the cell has no fill, and then re-filing back to blank from red, will actually fill the cell white - which is not technically the original color.

Comment: @BigBen: I've seen it, but the OP put red in the text. It is easily changed. But what about the overflow: 'If Selection.Cells.Count = 1' should mean only if 1 cell is selected.

Comment: Right - hit Ctrl + A in the worksheet. You'll get an overflow error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756467/target-count-causing-an-overflow-error

Comment: @BigBen: No Error here. Sorry, I'm using 2003 that hasn't that many cells. Don't be sad, we want to write code for all versions. Should I use Version?

Comment: Ahhhh got it, my bad. I guess it'll just be a note for OP, depending on the Excel version.

Comment: @BigBen: Don't be sad, we want to write code for all versions. Should I use Version? Will my excel compile with CountLarge?

Comment: I am not sure, up to you to try it :) From a brief Google search, looks like it was added in 2007.

Answer (score 0):

In Module

```
Public vColor(6 To 33)
Sub setColor()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim n As Integer
    n = 6
    For Each rng In Range("d6:d33")
        vColor(n) = rng.Interior.Color
        n = n + 1
    Next rng
End Sub
```

In Sheet code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    setColor
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D6:D33")) Is Nothing Then
           If Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 55, 55) Then
                Target.Interior.Color = vColor(Target.Row)
            Else
                Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 55, 55)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you may keep a `Dictionary` of clicked cells only:

```
Option Explicit

Dim colorsDict As Scripting.Dictionary

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D6:D33")) Is Nothing Then
            If colorsDict Is Nothing Then Set colorsDict = New Scripting.Dictionary ' instantiate a dictionary object
            With colorsDict ' reference dictionary object
                If .Exists(Target.Address) Then ' if selected cell already in dictionary (i.e. already selected)
                    Target.Interior.Color = .Item(Target.Address) ' get its "original" color back
                    .Remove Target.Address ' remove its address from dictionary (i.e. as if it was never selected before) 
                Else ' if selected cell not in dictionary (i.e. not already selected)
                    .Add Target.Address, IIf(Target.Interior.Color = 16777215, xlNone, Target.Interior.Color) ' keep track of its original color storing it into dictionary with cell target as key
                    Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 55, 55) ' color the selected cell with red
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```